# How to correctly set acl for www-data files?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I have web files stored on my server. Currently only the root has a full access:

```
drwxr-xr-x  6 root www-data  directory
-rw-r--r--  1 root www-data  file.php
```

The problem is that the developers wants to use their own account `su - myuser` to access and modify these files.

Unfortunately, the only solution I have found is to add these users to `www-data` group and make the php files writable by `www-data` which is ugly.

What alternative do I have?

Comment: Why are the developers modifying files on a production server? You should have at least a development server and maybe a staging server as well.

Comment: This is rather a development server than a production server, but the files get their permissions from the Git repository.

Comment: The other solution (of a dev server) is to put the files in the same groups as developers, with read-access by the server. Unless the server needs write access to its own files but this is even more ugly...

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to use **X** and not **x** for the executable.

**Step 1: Create Backup**

First make a backup incase anything goes wrong someday:

```
mkdir ~/storage-changes
sudo getfacl -R /var/www > ~/storage-changes/default_www_facl
```

### (Incase) To Restore

```
sudo setfacl --restore=~/storage-changes/default_www_facl
```

### Apply ACL

Next, apply to a group:

```
# -R is recursive
# -m is modify
# -d applies to default ACL

sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www
sudo setfacl -Rd g:www-data:rwX /var/www
sudo setfacl -Rdm g:www-data:rwX /var/www

ls -lta /var
sudo getfacl /var/www
```

The `+` at the end of the file/dir listing only means it has additional ACLs.

Answer (score 0):

If your Linux server isn't too old, and you are on a standard filesystem for Linux, you can use access control lists to give permissions to other users.

For example, the following command will give read and write permissions to the `myuser` user on `file`: `setfacl -m user:myuser:rw file`

`setfacl` may need to be installed, depending on your distribution.